# For what values does $kx^2 - 6x - 4 = 0$ cut the x-axis?

Tags: graphing-functions, quadratics

A quadratic equation problem.

> For what values does $kx^2 - 6x - 4 = 0$ cut the x-axis?

The preceding part of this question dealt with the discriminant.

Comment: Do you mean "For what values of $k$ does $f(x)=kx^2-6x-4$ cut the x-axis?"?

Comment: Use the quadratic formula.  When x has real solutions, it cuts the axis.

Comment: For a parabola to have $ \ x-$ intercepts, it must have real numbers for zeroes.  What does the discriminant of the quadratic formula tell you for this quadratic equation?

Comment: @user236182 On second thoughts, I suppose so.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Uh, k is less than zero.

Comment: @DougM Thank you very much! I understand now.

Comment: @DougM Except not when $k\neq 0$ and it's a parabola that touches the x-axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumingly you mean "For what values of $k$ does $f(x)=kx^2-6x-4$ cut the x-axis?".

A continuous function cuts the x-axis exactly at the points $x=x_i$ where $f(x_i)=0$ (and where $f(x)$ doesn't "touch" the x-axis).

The question is equivalent to "For what values of $k$ does the equation $kx^2-6x-4=0$ have a solution $x=x_i$ at which point $f(x)=kx^2-6x-4$ doesn't "touch" the x-axis?".

And a quadratic equation has a "non-touching" solution if and only if $\Delta=(-6)^2-4(k)(-4)> 0$ (the "touching" solution is if and only if $\Delta=0$).

But remember that the equation is only quadratic when $k\neq 0$. If $k=0$, the equation becomes $-6x-4=0$. Does this one have a solution?

Comment: I wouldn't say so, since it appears to have no real solutions. In that case I suppose there are no values at which the x-axis is cut.

Comment: @MadBanners It has the only solution $x=\frac{4}{-6}=-\frac{2}{3}$, which is a real number.

Comment: Ah, I must have done something wrong in the calculation. I'll try it again.

Comment: Well, for $k=-9/4$ the curve *touches* the $x$-axis, so it might be useful to state it explicitly.

Comment: Also, "show algebraically that the graph of y=x^2 + kx - 2 will cut the x-axis twice for all values of k."

Comment: So what's the discriminant for _that_ quadratic function?  Can it be negative? Or zero?

Comment: @egreg You're right. It might be necessary if touching doesn't count as cutting, but it depends on what you mean exactly by "cutting".

Comment: @user236182 That's why I'd add it explicitly (we don't know what meaning the OP uses the word with).